# Can bs4 get the dynamic content of a webpage if requests can't?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I've tried Selenium previously and now wanted to test out bs4. I tried running the following code but recieved `None` as an output.

```
res_pewdiepie = requests.get(
    'https://www.youtube.com/user/PewDiePie')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res_pewdiepie.content, "lxml")
subs = soup.find(id="sub-count")
print(subs)
```

After researching for a while, I found out that requests doesn't load dynamic content like the subcount on YouTube or Socialblade.  Is there a way to get this information with bs4 or if do I have to switch back to something like Selenium?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sometimes if you look at the network interaction happening on the background, you can be able to do a post or get request to a different domain to retrieve the information. In this case I was not able to find a workaround though. The page loaded with BS4 is the agree to their terms page. Perhaps you need to add the correct request headers and cookies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` can only parse a text you give it, in this case the page source. If the information is not there it can't do anything about it. So, I believe you have to switch back to something that supports javascript.

Some options:
[python-selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)
[requests-html](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/)

Answer (score 1):

I use [splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) for stuff like this. You can run it in a docker container. You can tweak how long it waits for rendering on a per-request basis. There's also a scrapy plugin if you're doing any serious crawling. Here's a snippet from one of my crawlers, running Splash locally using Docker. Good luck.

```
target_url = "https://somewhere.example.com/"
splash_url = "http://localhost:8050/render.json"
body = json.dumps({"url": target_url, "har": 0, "html": 1, "wait": 10,})
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

response = requests.post(splash_url, data=body, headers=headers)
result = json.loads(response.text)
html = result["html"]
```