# HTML extract with Python, accessing multiple <ul> elements in a div (Dynamic Content Issue)

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

so basically I tried to get some `<li>` items in a `<ul>` element, but those are multiple times appearing in one div element.

I already can extract information from the first `<ul>` element in the div but not the others, tried iterations and so on (BeautifulSoup with findAll but nothing works):

[image: Original HTML]

My code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

div = soup.find('div', class_='css-hfsu5e eyz9ve26') # the div class 

for ul in div.find_all('ul'):
    print(ul) # First ul in the div only (nothing else print...)
    for li in ul.find_all('li'):
        print(li) #Return the li elements but only for the first ul
```

The code output:

[Python Chunk Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2yDe.png)

**UPDATE:**

I followed Barmar recommendations and got it working with Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

# Initiate Storing
watches = []

# Launch a web browser and navigate to the web page
url = “website.com”
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the dynamic content to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul[aria-label="All models"].css-1totg6u.eyz9ve24')))

# Extract the HTML source code
html = driver.page_source

# Use Beautiful Soup to parse the HTML and extract the <li> elements
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
li_elements = soup.select('ul[aria-label="All models"].css-1totg6u.eyz9ve24')

for li_element in li_elements:
    for item in li_element:
        for ul in item.find_all("a", class_="css-1232gz9 e1wd4zgb6"):
```

Comment: Are you sure there are multiple `ul` in the HTML? Your screenshot shows the DOM, which might be updated dynamically with JavaScript. `requests.get()` won't get those udpates.

Comment: Use `View Source` in the browser to see what you're actually getting.

Comment: thanks for the quick answers, I will try now the view source, maybe dynamic is the issue, but I am not an expert in those ^^

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65265321/can-bs4-get-the-dynamic-content-of-a-webpage-if-requests-cant

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get your code working as you intend. This is the full listing; more or less identical to yours.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Prepare the link and get the content.
URL = "http://localhost:80/lala.html"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

# Get the top level container for the content I want and start
# narrowing it down.
div = soup.find('div',class_='css-hfsu5e eyz9ve26')

for ul in div.find_all('ul'):
    print(ul) # First ul in the div only (nothing else print...)
    for li in ul.find_all('li'):
        print(li) #Return the li elements but only for the first ul
```

The HTML I used for the test was:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1>This is the list test page</h1>
  <div class="css-hfsu5e eyz9ve26">
    <ul id="ul1">
      <li>list 1 a</li>
      <li>list 1 b</li>
      <li>list 1 c</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="ul2">
      <li>list 2 a</li>
      <li>list 2 b</li>
      <li>list 2 c</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="ul3">
    </ul>
    <ul id="ul4">
      <li>list 4 a</li>
      <li>list 4 b</li>
      <li>list 4 c</li>
      <li>list 4 d</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The output is as follows (confusing but expected because you're printing the 'ul' contents as well as each child 'li' so it looks like it's doubled up on first glance. But it works in any case so I'm guessing it's your page / data rather than your code. Although I don't think your full listing is included so not sure what steps you took to get the page data back.

$ ./stackoverflow_answer.py

```
<ul id="ul1">
<li>list 1 a</li>
<li>list 1 b</li>
<li>litt 1 c</li>
</ul>
<li>list 1 a</li>
<li>list 1 b</li>
<li>litt 1 c</li>
<ul id="ul2">
<li>list 2 a</li>
<li>list 2 b</li>
<li>litt 2 c</li>
</ul>
<li>list 2 a</li>
<li>list 2 b</li>
<li>litt 2 c</li>
<ul id="ul3">
</ul>
<ul id="ul4">
<li>list 4 a</li>
<li>list 4 b</li>
<li>litt 4 c</li>
<li>litt 4 d</li>
</ul>
<li>list 4 a</li>
<li>list 4 b</li>
<li>litt 4 c</li>
<li>litt 4 d</li>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I can also provide my new code working, using dynamic content !

Comment: I checked your answer in details, seems that you are using a different class id for the <ul>, which make it different from my original problem (check ul[aria-label="All models"].css-1totg6u.eyz9ve24 )

Comment: Yes. If the content is dynamic then that changes the game and something like selenium is necessary to render the content before parsing it with BeautifulSoup. Is it correct to say that was the problem and not your original python code?

Comment: I will change the title yes thanks ^^